# edit an xml file from flash as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

In the root my XML file is:

```
<object>
     <item>my item 1</item>
  <item>my item 2</item>
</object>
```

I want the result is:

```
<object>

    <item>my item 1 edited</item>
    <item>my item 2 edited</item>
</object>
```

can it be possible to edit external XML file by Actionscript using Flash. If possible then how?

Comment: are u asking about editing an external file with xml content within flash or how to edit xml data specifically, from an external file?

Comment: I am asking how to edit an xml file using actionscript.

Comment: let me explain my project first. We have a text input type on screen where the data is coming from an xml file. we need to edit it in place and the xml data also be updated. reading and writing the xml.

Comment: do you want to edit the xml as if it were a text file, or do you want an editable tree structure?

Comment: I want that the xml node which is being called into the flash should be edited. neither the structure should be effected. because the next time if users open the same flash file he should see the changed content.

Comment: You can only work with file system using Adobe AIR. Web based applications written in Flash can't access files without the permission of a user.

Comment: he can load it with browse file then override it with flash

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar to my map editor that saves and loads xml?
http://zoron19.deviantart.com/art/ParkourEditor-395279691

Comment: My requirement is a little bit different from the link. I want to edit xml nodes on server not locally. Thanks for reply!